# jsonb searching for keys in array and returning position

Tags: postgresql

I have the following json object stored into a jsonb column

```
{
  "msrp": 6000,
  "data": [
    {
      "supplier": "a",
      "price": 5775
    },
    {
      "supplier": "b",
      "price": 6129
    },
    {
      "supplier": "c",
      "price": 5224
    },
    {
      "supplier": "d",
      "price": 5775
    }
  ]
}
```

There's a few things I'm trying to do but completely stuck on :(

1. Check if a supplier exists inside this array.  So if I'm looking up if "supplier": "e" is in here.  Here's what I tried but didn't work.  "where data @> '{"supplier": "e"}'"
2. (optional but really nice to have) Before returning results if I do a select *, inject into each array a "price_diff" so that I can see the difference between msrp and the supplier price as such.

   ```
   {
     "supplier": "d",
     "price": 5775,
     "price_diff": 225
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> where data @> '{"supplier": "e"}'
> ```

Do you have a column named data?  You can't just treat a JSONB key name as if it were a column name.

Containment starts from the root.

```
colname @> '{"data":[{"supplier": "e"}]}'
```

You can redefine the 'root' dynamically though:

```
colname->'data' @> '[{"supplier": "e"}]'
```